# Count how often integer y occurs right after integer x in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, count, frequency

I have a very large `numpy.array` of integers, where each integer is in the range `[0, 31]`.

I would like to **count**, for every pair of integers `(a, b)` in the range `[0, 31]` (e.g. `[0, 1], [7, 9], [18, 0]`) how often `b` occurs right after `a`.

This would give me a `(32, 32)` matrix of counts.

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this with numpy. Raw python loops would be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way...

To make the example easier to read, I'll use a maximum value of 9 instead of 31:

```
In [178]: maxval = 9
```

Make a random input for the example:

```
In [179]: np.random.seed(123)

In [180]: x = np.random.randint(0, maxval+1, size=100)
```

Create the result, initially all 0:

```
In [181]: counts = np.zeros((maxval+1, maxval+1), dtype=int)
```

Now add 1 to each coordinate pair, using [`numpy.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) to ensure that duplicates are counted properly:

```
In [182]: np.add.at(counts, (x[:-1], x[1:]), 1)

In [183]: counts
Out[183]: 
array([[2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2],
       [0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0]])
```

For example, the number of times 6 is followed by 1 is

```
In [188]: counts[6, 1]
Out[188]: 4
```

We can verify that with the following expression:

```
In [189]: ((x[:-1] == 6) & (x[1:] == 1)).sum()
Out[189]: 4
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. Though I need to investigate how this numpy function actually works to understand what's happening!

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy's built-in `diff` routine together with boolean arrays.

```
import numpy as np    

test_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7])
a, b = (1, 2)

sum(np.bitwise_and(test_array[:-1] == a, np.diff(test_array) == b - a))
# 3
```

If your array is multi-dimensional, you will need to flatten it first or make some small modifications to the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Even though your solution is elegant it is actually slower than a raw python loop.